# JavaScript async/await: await is a reserved word

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await

Here is a function that checks on mongoose for duplicate records. In that case `name` and `email` are unique fields, so if a record with the same name or email is on database a new one cannot be inserted:

```
const checkIfDatabaseHasUsersWithSameNameAndEmail = async () => {

    uniques = ['name', 'email'];
    uniques.map((field) => {
        let query = {};
        query[field] = data[field];
        query.deleted = false;
        let result = await model.findOne(query); <== ERROR: await is a reserved word

        if (result) {
            errors.push({
                field: field,
                message: 'A record already exists in database for ' + field + '=' + data[field]
            });
        }
    });

    if (errors.length > 0)
        return errors;
}

schema.statics.create = function (data) {

    let errors = await checkIfDatabaseHasUsersWithSameNameAndEmail(); <== ERROR: await is a reserved word

    if (errors)
        throw new Error(errorMessages);

    let company = new this(data);
    return company.save();
}
```

When running I´m getting the following error pointed out on code: `await is a reserved word`

This is my first time using async/await, so probably I´m doing it the wrong way. My goal is to run que unique tests (findOne) in sequence and if everything goes fine save the new register.

Comment: You're using `await` in the non-async callback passed to `.map()`.

Comment: The anonymous function in which you are actually using `await` is not declared `async`.

Comment: Yup. Scope issue.

Comment: Thanks all for comments, but... What exactly should I fix in code ?

Comment: @Mendes can you tell us what this is supposed to do? Do you expect `findAny` to return something to you? If so, what should it return?

Comment: I will edit and put a complete scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you're trying to await something, but haven't declared the function async. I didn't test this with mongoose, but it will look something like this.

```
async function checkIfDatabaseHasUsersWithSameNameAndEmail(data) {
  const uniques = ['name', 'email'];
  return Promise.all(uniques.map(async (field) => {
    const query = {};
    query[field] = data[field];
    query.deleted = false;
    return model.findOne(query);
  }));
}

schema.statics.create = async function create(data) {
  try {
    const results = await checkIfDatabaseHasUsersWithSameNameAndEmail(data);
    results.forEach((result) => {
      console.log(`Here's the issue: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
      throw new Error('Do something about it.');
    });

    const company = new this(data);
    return company.save();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Comment: This will make the mapper function return `Promise`'s ...

Comment: which you could then conveniently pass to Promise.all